# Querying with Associations in Sequelize

Tags: mysql, node.js, sequelize.js

I am using Sequelizer in my nodejs project and i couldn't make up anything from the official docs. Yet i managed to create tables and add rows etc. But the problem is that i need to query for objects with some special conditions on their associations.

I have a **user** model, a **vote** model and a **Position** model. A use can vote for an other user in a position. So this is the code that makes up the relations :

```
Position.hasMany(User,{as: 'Candidate'});
Votes.belongsToMany(User,{through: 'UserVote'});
User.belongsToMany(Votes,{through: 'UserVote'});
```

the problem is that i didn't find a way to query for the Positions which one known user didn't vote for yet. How do i do that ?

Answer (score 1):

I am not 100% how to do that with associations but I will try to show you how I would do it using a regular query.  Excuse the syntax if it isn't exactly perfect, this is just from memory.  Assuming you have a user identifier provided (I'll call it userId).

Edit: I also noticed you are using MySQL.  This works in Postgres but you might need to tweak the syntax for it to work for you.  I don't know MySQL specifics but this should be close enough for you to get the idea!

```
Position.findAll({
  where: [
    `NOT EXISTS(
      SELECT 1
        FROM "votes"
       WHERE "votes"."position_id" = "position"."id" AND
         "votes"."user_id" = ${userId}
    )`
  ]
}).then(...);
```

I have not found a better way to query existence yet myself.  This pattern is usually my go-to for these kinds of queries.  I made a few assumptions about your actual database model.

Also good to note that this is for Sequelize 3.x.x but I think it should more or less work on 4.x.x.

Good luck! :)

Comment: Thank you but as expected the Literal replacement in Where was removed in latest versions of Sequelize, but i will try and see how to use your code's semantic elsewhere. Thanks

Comment: prepared statement like this where: ['"votes"."user_id" = ?', userId]

Comment: they don't work either, the official docs only state one easy case 
`// Find all projects with a least one task where task.state === project.task
Project.findAll({
    include: [{
        model: Task,
        where: { state: Sequelize.col('project.state') }
    }]
})`
 Which doesn't really work when having a JoinTable

Comment: https://github.com/sequelize/sequelize/issues/6529 would something like that help you?  I've never played too much with Sequelize 4.x.x but maybe you could do `where: { '$votes.user_id$': userId }` or something similar to that.  If that works I'll update my answer for other folks because it's not the most obvious thing in the world.

Comment: No actually that is not what i want to do at all. What i want to do is to :
Positions.FindAll Where Position.User.Votes.PositionId!=ID, while ID is known already. I already do this so easily when using doctrine but on sequelize it is so damn complicated.